# Image as a website border

Tags: html, css

How do I use a image as a border for the sides of my website? For example if I wanted Candy Canes or Tanks to go down both sides.

I have only found how to use a image as a border around text but have not found a way to get a image to go down both sides with the image repeated.

Comment: Look at my answer and if that's what you were looking for you could comment and rate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though you never framed your question properly, hope this gives you an idea. Just make an image with the border you need and then apply it on the body tag tweaking around the border and border-image properties.

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  border: 40px solid transparent;
  padding: 15px;
  border-image: url(http://weclipart.com/gimg/FA9DE696CE3D1CC3/candy-cane-border-vector-100696.jpg) 70 round;
}
```

```html
RANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM
STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM
STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM
STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM
STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM
STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM
STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM
STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM STUFFRANDOM
```